# remove msbuild console warning but keep warning in log file

Tags: msbuild

I am building VC++ project using msbuild in batch file. I get about 1500 of same type of warnings (C4554). When running on a build server, i want that warning not be displayed on console window but they be logged in log file.
I have tried couple of methods like

```
 call %MSBuildToolsPathVS%/msbuild %SolFilePath% /p:configuration=debug;WarningLevel=0;Platform=x64^
  /flp:LogFile=%MSBuildLogPath%;Verbosity=normal^
```

or even this

```
call %MSBuildToolsPathVS%/msbuild %SolFilePath% /p:configuration=debug;WarningLevel=0;Platform=x64^
 /clp:Summary^
 /flp:LogFile=%MSBuildLogPath%;Verbosity=normal^
```

or

```
call %MSBuildToolsPathVS%/msbuild %SolFilePath% /p:configuration=debug;Platform=x64;WarningLevel=0;RunCodeAnalysis=false^
 /clp:Summary^
 /flp:LogFile=%MSBuildLogPath%;Verbosity=normal^
```

still displays the warning on console.

```
call %MSBuildToolsPathVS%/msbuild %SolFilePath% /p:configuration=debug;Platform=x64^
 /clp:ErrorsOnly^
 /flp:LogFile=%MSBuildLogPath%;Verbosity=normal^
 /t:rebuild
```

causes log file to display warnings correctly but the console now hides the warnings but it also dosn't show usual steps of what configuration is being build, the target that is built etc, which is the information I want.

Any solutions?
sedy

Comment: whosoever did so, before flagging down,let me know the reason

Comment: This is not possible with the standard logger: there's no way to tell it to skip a certain line. You'll have to write a custom logger and make it log everything to the console except lines containing a warning. Better yet would be to just fix the warning.